# Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation

Tags: excel, vba, out-of-memory

**Scenario**

I have two userforms whereby when I click a button in the first userform, a second one will show and then unload the first userform.

**Problem**

I am having memory error when I click on one `listbox` present in the second userform

My `userform2` as below

[image]

And the error as below

[image]

Below are the whole codes in the `userform2`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

        Dim reportWbi As Workbook
        Dim internal As Worksheet

        Set reportWbi = Workbooks.Add(reportFile)
        Set internal = reportWbi.Worksheets("Internal")
        internal.Select

        LastAddress = internal.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address
        ListBox2.RowSource = "C6:" & LastAddress

        reportWbi.Close savechanges:=False
        Set reportWbi = Nothing
        Set internal = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    reportCreator.Show
End Sub
```

Actually there is not much variables or stuffs inside. After debug one by one, I noticed, without the following lines, there are no memory errors

```
    reportWbi.Close savechanges:=False
    Set reportWbi = Nothing
    Set internal = Nothing
```

The moment I gave the line `reportWbi.Close savechanges:=False`, it is throwing out memory error.

Just a side note that I am using office 365 and 8Gb RAM. I don't think this is causing any issue

Does anyone knows what is wrong?

**Edit 1**

I tried this whole code into a brand excel file with only one userform and having the same memory error. The moment I removed `reportWbi.Close savechanges:=False`, everything works fine without any error

**Edit 2**

I removed the `ListBox2.RowSource = "C6:" & LastAddress` code and this time also no error even with `reportWbi.Close savechanges:=False` present

Its very confusing why this happening. Please someone help if know anything about this

Comment: Try to workbook.SaveAs first in a specified path.

Comment: I did that way. But the moment I tried to close that file, the error pop up again

Comment: And it happens only when I click on the listbox and not when loading the userform

Comment: 1. There is no event code for that listbox so I don't know how it's causing an issue. 2. Try putting a breakpoint on `reportCreator.Show` and see if that is being called when the workbook is being closed.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid
1. For this case, without event code also when i click on the `listbox`, it is throwing the memory error
2. Yes it is calling `reportCreator` userform

Comment: Does `reportCreator.Show` run without issue?

Comment: When I click on the `listbox`, it is throwing the error. Once I acknowledge it, and then it shows `reportCreator`. But this time the error will show once again. Once acknowledge, program will work as normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trials, found out that issue was due to `ListBox2.RowSource = "C6:" & LastAddress` this `RowSource` property. I don't know why it caused memory issue though. I removed this and populate `Listbox2` using some other loop method as below

```
        Range("C6").Select
        Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
            With ListBox2
                .AddItem ActiveCell.Value
            End With
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
```

Now there is no memory issues and everything works fine